# On D.O., where to file reports for spam users?

Tags: community-official-site, advertising

On drupal.org, where does one file reports for a suspected spam account?

My [google searches](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS430US430&ix=sea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=spam%20drupal.org#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS430US430&sclient=psy-ab&q=spam%20account%20drupal.org&oq=spam%20account%20drupal.org&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=12220l13973l0l14092l14l11l2l0l0l2l137l955l8.3l15l0&gs_l=serp.3...12220l13973l0l14092l14l11l2l0l0l2l137l955l8j3l15l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=190a38aff74067d&biw=1280&bih=923&ix=sea) have turned out results about a spam module and such.

Comment: What reported by Berdir is correct; for a discussion about any future changes to how spam is handled, see [Spam - meta: better spam-combating suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1293186).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is creating an issue in the [webmaster queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters). There is a Spam category there.

Comment: The list of all the spam reports is the [following one](http://drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=task&component=Spam).